# How to define a JSON variable with immutable properties?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

We have created a JSON constant we are sharing with various LWC. While we can define the JSON reference as const, the properties on the object can be changed by calling code.

For example:

```
const constants = {
    label: '30 years',
    value: 30
};
```

While we cannot do this:

```
constants = 'ABC';
```

We can do this:

```
constants.label = '20 years';
```

Is there a way to lock down the properties of the JSON so that they cannot be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a basic level, you can just freeze the object:

```
const constants = { label: '30 years', value: 30 }
Object.freeze(constants);
```

You can also use an immutable membrane, which you can start by using salesforce's [ObservableMembrane](https://github.com/salesforce/observable-membrane) implementation. Unlike Object.freeze, this protects an object's properties recursively, making the entire object graph immutable.